# Integration Objective C Protocols with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, integration, protocols

I am new in swift and i need some help to integrate 
a component AKPickerView (written in Objective C).
link of component: https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView

But i have no success, because there is a protocol: *AKPickerViewDelegate* that don't work in Swift:

```
@class AKPickerView;

@protocol AKPickerViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (NSString *)pickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView titleForItem:(NSInteger)item;
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInPickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView;
- (void)pickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item;
@end
```

In Swift i wrote this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AKPickerViewDelegate {

var pickerView : AKPickerView = AKPickerView()
var titles     : NSArray = ["Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio"]

...
```

And I implimented this methods:

```
func numberOfItemsInPickerView(pickerView : AKPickerView!) -> Int{

    return self.titles.count
}


func pickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView, titleForItem item : NSInteger) -> NSString {

    return self.titles[item] as NSString
}
```

But the compiler show this error:

```
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'AKPickerViewDelegate'
```

Appreciate some help
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the arguments in your overridden methods might not quite match the protocol. You're returning `Int` when it expects `NSUInteger` (bad), but accepting `NSInteger` in a place that provides `NSInteger` (good). So there's a bit of a discrepancy there. Can you try returning `NSUInteger` or `UInt` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i have seen in link `AKPickerViewDelegate` has required method.

```
@protocol AKPickerViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInPickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView;
- (NSString *)pickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView titleForItem:(NSInteger)item;
@optional
- (void)pickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item;
@end
```

So in swift you need to implement them.Implement these methods as below and it will remove the error

```
func numberOfItemsInPickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView!) -> UInt {

    return self.titles.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView!, titleForItem item: Int) -> String! {

   return self.titles[item]
}
```

**Note** you also need to add them in Bridging Header.Just write this `#import "AKPickerView.h"` in `Swifter-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: Hi Codester! Thank for help! The difference was in NSString and String and Int and UInt.

Comment: Yes @Weles swift is strongly typed language so does not convert implicitly to other types