# Swift agreement issue, how to express

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
@protocol XXXDelegate <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, strong) XXX
@end
id<XXXDelegate> msg = obj;
[msg XXX]
```

1.`id<XXXDelegate> msg = obj` 
  in swift is how to write this type

Use swift how to express a generic follow a protocol...?

Thankyou.

Comment: check this link ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981568/integration-objective-c-protocols-with-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if you intend to store a reference to some type conforming to the protocol `XXXDelegate` you would need to write this like `var delegate: XXXDelegate?`.

If you are asking about referencing the concrete class matching the protocol - there is no easy way (it is against the overall idea of swift protocol). You can use generic function/class constraints to do so or use a technique called type erasure.

The first one is more straight forward

```
class Generic<T: SomeClass> where T: XXXDelegate {
    var delegate: T?     
}
```